# What does this double subquery using NOT EXISTS for both actually return?

Tags: oracle, subquery, double, exists

I have a SQL query that I am trying to understand what it does in plain English not how the query works but I am struggling to understand. The query is this:

```
SELECT S#
FROM S
WHERE NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT *
      FROM P
      WHERE NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT *
            FROM SP
            WHERE S.S# = SP.S#
            AND   P.P# = SP.P#));
```

and the schema for that query is this:

```
S(S#,Sname,Status,City)
P(P#, Pname, Colour, Weight, City)
SP(S#, P#, Qty)
```

Where S is a supplier, P is a part and SP is the table listing which supplier produce which part.

My current understanding is that this returns all the supplier numbers who do not produce any parts however I do not get if that is correct.

Comment: _Silly Question_ Did you run it to see what it returns?

Comment: _Small Note_ You tagged `Mysql` and `Oracle` **which one is it**

Comment: Its oracle Sorry, I deleted the Mysql tag and I have but it doesn't actually return anything, so I am confused to what it should do. I was given the query its not something I have written my self.

Comment: This query should be forbidden, as it makes the opposite of what one would think;) Anyway plus 1 for the challenge:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Show all supplier that supply ALL existing parts**

The best way to understand is small example:

```
create table s as
select 1 s# from dual union all
select 2 s# from dual union all
select 3 s# from dual;

create table p as
select 1 p# from dual union all
select 2 p# from dual;

create table sp as
select 1 s#, 1 p# from dual union all
select 1 s#, 2 p# from dual union all
select 2 s#, 1 p# from dual;
```

Now S# 1 supplies P# 1 and 2

S# 2 only P# 1 and

S# 3 nothing

```
SELECT S#
FROM S
WHERE NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT *
      FROM P
      WHERE NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT *
            FROM SP
            WHERE S.S# = SP.S#
            AND   P.P# = SP.P#));


        S#
----------
         1
```

It is not the simplest query to be explained, but maybe this help:

This subquery

```
 (SELECT *
  FROM P
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT *
        FROM SP
        WHERE S.S# = SP.S#
        AND   P.P# = SP.P#))
```

return all `products` that are **not supplied** by the supplier `S.S#`.

So this subquery return **no rows** in case the supplier provides all products, which makes the `NOT EXISTS`predicate TRUE.